# Locating the same DOM in multiple locations in a document

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

Upon the user changing a select element, JavaScript is used to show or hide which inputs are available in a form.  Some inputs are shown/used regardless of the select element's value, yet others are unique for each value.  Currently, I have one form which handles all scenarios, however, it is getting complicated and using jQuery validate is next to impossible.

```
<form>
    <select name="type" id="type"><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Typ2 2</option></select>
    <select name="theme" id="theme"><option value="1">Theme 1</option><option value="2">Theme 2</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <div id="type1">
        <input type="text" name="type1_1">
        <input type="text" name="type1_2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="type1_3">
    </div>
    <div id="type2">
        <input type="text" name="type2_1">
        <select name="type2_2"><option value="1">xxx 1</option><option value="2">xxx</option></select>
    </div>
    <div id="type3">
        <input type="text" name="type3_1">
        <select name="type3_2"><option value="1">xxx 1</option><option value="2">xxx</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="type3_3">
    </div>
    <div id="type4">
        <input type="text" name="type4_1">
        <input type="text" name="type4_2">
        <select name="type4_3"><option value="1">xxx 1</option><option value="2">xxx</option></select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Using individual forms will simplify portions, however, I prefer not to duplicate the HTML in each form.

```
<form id="form1">
    <select name="type" id="type"><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Typ2 2</option></select>
    <select name="theme" id="theme"><option value="1">Theme 1</option><option value="2">Theme 2</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <div id="type1">
        <input type="text" name="type1_1">
        <input type="text" name="type1_2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="type1_3">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <select name="type" id="type"><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Typ2 2</option></select>
    <select name="theme" id="theme"><option value="1">Theme 1</option><option value="2">Theme 2</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <div id="type2">
        <input type="text" name="type2_1">
        <select name="type2_2"><option value="1">xxx 1</option><option value="2">xxx</option></select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="form3">
    <select name="type" id="type"><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Typ2 2</option></select>
    <select name="theme" id="theme"><option value="1">Theme 1</option><option value="2">Theme 2</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <div id="type3">
        <input type="text" name="type3_1">
        <select name="type3_2"><option value="1">xxx 1</option><option value="2">xxx</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="type3_3">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="form4">
    <select name="type" id="type"><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Typ2 2</option></select>
    <select name="theme" id="theme"><option value="1">Theme 1</option><option value="2">Theme 2</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <div id="type4">
        <input type="text" name="type4_1">
        <input type="text" name="type4_2">
        <select name="type4_3"><option value="1">xxx 1</option><option value="2">xxx</option></select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

One option is to use individual forms which don't include the common inputs and then use JavaScript to set hidden inputs upon submit.

Another option is to use JavaScript to move the DOM associated with the common inputs into the applicable form upon submit, however, am concerned that doing so might get buggy if various forms are used upon a single page load.

Before going down this path, is it possible to use JavaScript to display the same DOM multiple locations in the same document?  When I say "same", I don't mean a clone of it, but that each location somehow references the same object elements. Would doing so allow each individual form to include these common "referenced" input elements?

Comment: No, what you're asking for at the end is not possible. I guess your validation issues should probably reduce themselves by a lot already, if you started properly disabling form fields that are not relevant under the current conditions, instead of just visually hiding them from the user ...? (Any form validation that wasn't capable of taking `disabled` into account would be a rewrite-from-scratch candidate anyway, right?)

Comment: @CBroe   Agree using `disabled` solve the validation issues, however, liked the idea of multiple small forms if possible.  Oh well... Thank you form your comment.